# Bytes in a 32 bit system?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am in the process of interviewing at a few places and I saw this question in one of the discussion forums.

> How many bytes are contained in a 32
>   bit system?

The answer given is 2^29 or 536870912 - I believe it's because a 32 bit system can address 2^32 bits of memory and 8 bits to a byte gives 2^32/8 = 2^29 bytes. 
Can someone confirm if I'm on the right track?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't like this interview question. How do we know if its RAM, video RAM, filesystem, etc?

Comment: The given answer is wrong, in almost all contexts. The question is also very badly phrased. If I were you, I'd ignore it completely, or at least find a clearer version.

Comment: @michael @mathepic - yes the question was really open ended. I guess the interviewers were expecting the candidate to ask further questions to clarify

Comment: My 32bit PC has 2GB of RAM, two 320GB hard disks and a 1TB external drive attached. (Note that an advertised GB is a different size for RAM vs storage). Plus some dedicated video memory and other assorted memory associated with devices. BIOS storage on the motherboard. 128bits or whatever for the battery-powered internal clock counter. I might have left a DVD in the drive. So how many bytes does it "contain"? The answer given is 512MB, so to figure out how someone got it you'll have to figure out what system has 512MB of what kind of memory.

Comment: This question is idiotic, but I'm not downvoting because it's not OP being stupid but rather the interviewer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addressable unit is a byte, not a bit.

So 32bit pointer allows to address 2^32 bytes.

Comment: @tom: modified c-smile's answer.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

If the question really was: "How many bytes are in a 2^32 bit system?", the answer is correct.

(But still bad phrased)

Answer (score 1):

It's not that 2**32 **bits** are accessible, it's that 2**32 **words** are accessible. If we say 4 bytes per word, then 2**34 bytes is a closer value.

Although traditional systems are byte-oriented and therefore could access 2**32 bytes.

Comment: Well, on x86, what's accessible is 2**32 bytes, not bits or words. Other architectures might vary.